# How to customize gitlab jobs for different runners with tags

Tags: gitlab

This problem would be solved if Gitlab had supported the OR-logic tags: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/60007

I need to prepare different jobs to work differently on different runners. For example to use a different image in Kubernetes vs Openshift vs a laptop running a runner. Same thing goes for the before_script block.

Example job:

```
stages:
  - deploy

default:
  before_script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_RUNNER_TAGS" == *"kube"* ]]; then
      ..... do some stuff here
      fi
      if [[ "$CI_RUNNER_TAGS" == *"openshift"* ]]; then
      ..... do some stuff here
      fi

deploy:
  tags:
    - openshift
    - kube
```

The runners are set up like this:

- one runner can run any task thrown an it
- one runner can run only certain tasks, for example the one tagged kube

Currently the job executes only on a runner that has both tags. I would like to execute it on any runner that has one of the tags. Or perhaps there is a different way to achieve this.